# What cause a "Spike Load" in Load Testing?

Tags: scala, performance, gatling

I am a new user to Gatling and Scala, I have tried to set up a script and send to reqres.in, however when I check the report, there seems to be some spike load as below
[image: Graph]

What/Why these spikes appear and how does it affect the load testing analysis, any help would be appreciated.

Try to change to some lower traffic size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's no spike in your chart, just some minor variations.

Then the charts in the free reports display an ["active user" metric](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/stats/timings/#active-users), not started users nor concurrent users.

The variations are just some artifacts because of when users get started and terminate compared to the bounds of each second bucket.

Comment: just a little question in there, I define an expected concurrent users to be 30, however using throttle with reachRps(30), will add up which makes 60 users, is there a way that I can change the Rps but not affecting the Concurrent Users ?

Comment: Don't use throttle. Properly design your scenario in a way that's realistic for your use case and what your users do in production.